# How to extract certain content from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have an `NSString` like this:

```
<param name=\"movie\" value=\"system/swf/miniplayer.swf\"> 
param name=\"FlashVars\"
value=\"playerID=1&amp;soundFile=audios/programAudios/f37070041634e8d19316422e3ffad4c9.mp3\"   
<param name=\"quality\" value=\"high\"  
<param name=\"menu\" value=\"false\" 
<param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"
<embed src=\"system/swf/miniplayer.swf\" width=\"180\" height=\"30\" 
flashvars=\"playerID=1&amp;soundFile=audios/programAudios/f37070041634e8d19316422e3ffad4c9.mp3\ 
quality=\"high\" menu=\"false\" wmode=\"transparent\"                          ",
```

How to extract **audios/programAudios/f37070041634e8d19316422e3ffad4c9.mp3**?

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Why are all your double-quotes escaped? Does it really look like that in the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *names = [nameString componentsSeparatedByString:@"soundFile="];
```

at the **second** **index of names** will be your path but you need to cut the other part
a fast way is that

```
NSArray *path = [nameString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\"];
```

at **first index of path** is your answer

Not perfect example of coding but it's works:)

Answer (score 1):

Your data does not look right, assuming it represents some XML string. Assuming that it ***is*** XML and that each 'param' properly ends with a `>`, you can use regular expressions to parse out the necessary information. I show some pseudocode below, you can adapt it to your needs. Please note that this example assumes there may be multiple `soundFile` sections in the input string.

```
NSString *data = @"param name=\"FlashVars\" value=\"playerID=1&amp;soundFile=audios/programAudios/f37070041634e8d19316422e3ffad4c9.mp3>\"";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
                                regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(soundFile=)(.+)(>)"
                                options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                error:&error];
if(error == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Number of capture groups: %lu\n", [regex numberOfCaptureGroups]);

    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:data options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [data length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSRange rangeOfInterest = [match rangeAtIndex:2];
        NSLog(@"Sound file: %@\n", [data substringWithRange: rangeOfInterest]);
    }
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

You can read more about Cocoa's support for regular expressions on their [documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Also, note that it may be more appropriate to use an XML parser and XPath queries to retrieve this information, but in this case regular expressions will do the job just fine.

Comment: unfortunately it was html response of some site from where i had to extract those media links. thanks